# Bootstrap datatable top and bottom border not showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, responsive

In iphone7, bootstrap responsive datatable top and bottom border not showing full border after table scroll left side.

After loading images and error image attach here..
[first image after loading page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNtRr.jpg) 
[error image after table scroll to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvqah.jpg)

Comment: Please provide code that reproduces the behaviour.

Comment: I had issue of div overlay in data-table responsive. try it by replacing following code from dataTables.bootstrap.min.css hope this will help you.   div.dataTables_info{padding-top:8px;white-space:nowrap;float: left;width: 100%;}